# MvcSiteMapProvider - understanding dynamicnodes

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I'm new to MvcSiteMapProvider. I have done the basics and understand that I have to setup my ***mvc.sitemap*** xml in order for breadcrumbs to work.

Now I want to be able to add dynamic nodes on click of links. 
For e.g When I click Apple in Category table : Phones. I want to be able to display ***Phones > Apple***.

So far I have seen this method everywhere:

```
public class FBDynamicNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase 
{        
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode mapnode)
    {
        var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();
        DynamicNode node = new DynamicNode();
        node.Title = "Nodedummytitle";
        node.Controller ="Phones";
        node.Action = "Index";
        node.RouteValues.Add("id", 1);
        node.ParentKey = "PhonesCategory";
        node.Key = "PhonesList";
        returnValue.Add(node);

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

But I really fail to understand how to get this working. I have tried debugging it, the **getdynamicnodecollection** method gets called but I don't see the breadcrumbs. What am I doing wrong? Can someone please share an example link which will help me to achieve this?

**EDIT 1:**
I solved this by identifying what was in my **website/sitemap.xml**. 
Apparently the breadcrumb was generated but not displayed because of incorrect uri.All I had to do is make the URI similar to that in my xml and it worked like a charm.

Now I'm stuck with a problem, wherein I don't know, what to do when I resolve my own question like another of my [SO Question's here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882214/fql-graph-api-fetch-all-posts-on-a-fan-page).

Please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the term "dynamic node" is a bit misleading. The nodes are not dynamic, they are static nodes that are based on a (potentially) dynamic data source. What this means is that they are loaded and stored in the shared cache at application startup (and whenever the cache expires). But they can be based on an external source such as a file or database.

Secondly, the matching behavior of the nodes is something that requires some understanding to achieve. It is pretty simple to get routes with no custom parameters to match, but when you add an "id" or other custom key to the route, you must also add it to the node's RouteValues dictionary for it to determine the "current node". By default you are expected to add a node for each "id" (which is typically done with dynamic nodes).

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Project 1" controller="Project" action="Details" id="1">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Project 2" controller="Project" action="Details" id="2">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Project 3" controller="Project" action="Details" id="3">
```

There is another option that works well if you just want to create some fake breadcrumbs to go with administration pages that edit data. This will make a node always match a route key regardless of its value, which is usually the ideal solution for administration pages that do CRUD operations.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit Project" controller="Project" action="Edit" preservedRouteParameters="id">
```

For a detailed look at these options, read the post [How to Make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position).